# Is there a shortcut to comment out multiple lines in Marvel Sense?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I can comment out one line at the time with `#`, but is there a multiple lines comment toggle keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I don't think so. Tried various things and looked at the source code and I don't there is any way to use a shortcut or even having a block of comments, like `/*......*/` in java.

Comment: Well hopefully at some point in the future this will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be done easily if you use vim
Specifically you could use macros .
Start recording a macro by typing qa where a will be the command name later.
Then type 0 to go to start of line . enter insert mode with i type # Esc and j to jump to next line.
type q to stop recording
now invoke command by typing 10 @a.

Answer (score 0):

there's not no

but marvel sense is super old, 5.X era. do you mean Kibana Console? if so, definitely raise a feature request for this :)

Comment: ahh the woes of SO, this was from '15, and yes these days it is Kibana Console, but in a sense that product has not evolved much since the early days. As to raising a feature request, this would be so low on their list of priorities that I am not sure it is worth my or their time. I copy JSONs to and from editors as needed.

Comment: fair point, but a FR makes it known either way :)